# Strange undefined margin from top on <body> element

Tags: html, css

I needed to migrate a website from windows server to linux server and implement human-readable urls. I applied the logic and all, but the css seems to act differently. The content is broken (it goes under the slider), but I wil fix that later. My main issue is that spacing from top that appeared and I cannot find what causes it. I know the website is damn ugly, but that's not my job. :)

Old server (how it should look like): http://newbalkanpolitics.org.mk/cat.php?id=137&lang=1&page=1&issue=138

New server: http://test.kiamotors.com.mk/cat/issue-14/138

The css files are completely the same on both servers (I did minor changes on the new one since it was broken, but that didn't change anything).

Comment: **first :** you should post code rather than url, **second**, your test url takes a lifetime in opening :p

Comment: **First**: Yeah, I know, but I don't know what code to paste here... I'm confused and I don't know where the problem comes from. **Second**: I don't know why, it goes smooth from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `margin-top: 30px` on `#content` that's causing it. On the first website, it has some inline style that affects it, I'm guessing JavaScript, which doesn't exist on the second.

Comment: That's it, thanks. I'll accept it as an answer in 6 minutes when it will allow me.

Answer (score 1):

You problem in position: absolute of #header change it to position: relative:

```
#header {
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Update:

position: relative for #slider-wrapper need to:

```
#slider-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

If you need header width 100% of window width then you must also change your CSS to like this:

```
#innerWrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    width: 978px;
}
```

Comment: The website has different layouts on different issues, and the #header tag is inside #innerWrapper, which is not 100% wide, so I'm guessing it was made this way because they needed a 100% wide header in this layout. Valid point though.